# What is the best approach to create a new player for a space game

Tags: core-data, swift3

I am a newbie and I have been learning swift off and on for a few months. I am looking to write a simple space mining game just to learn swift. I am not looking to post it to Appstore or anything like that.
I am wondering what is the best approach to create a new player that will hold player id and name. When you create a new player the player also gets three cargo ships (CargoShip class with id, name, speed, cargosize, level etc). 
Do I create a new struct that will store the new player and 3 cargo ships as an array called ShipFleet? 
Should the player class have a ShipFleet variable of type array to store the ships.
Should I create a new class of FleetShips to store the ships and add that class to the player class.
Should I be using Core Data to save all this data as Entities and attributes. 
What would be the standard approach to create and save this data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think that this question is a bit too broad and subjective to be answered here. Perhaps you could try something first, and if you encounter any problems, come back here with a more specific question. BTW, I think your ideas seem ok to start out.

Comment: Fair comment. I will think about it a bit more, try to keep it simple, code it, expand it and post for help on any specific issues I run into. I am still keen to know what the store best storage option? I am thinking Core Data?

Comment: CoreData is a useful thing to know about and should do what you need (...not to say other things won't).  I find that laying out a CoreData schema helps me think about how objects in a program relate to each other.